# Android cant see attr style

Tags: android

Im working with leanback library

```
implementation "com.android.support:leanback-v17:27.1.1"
```

this library has layout

```
android.support.v17.leanback.R.layout.lb_action_2_lines

<Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/lb_action_button"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="@dimen/lb_action_2_lines_height"
style="?attr/detailsActionButtonStyle"
android:lines="2"
/>
```

But styles not working.... **?attr/detailsActionButtonStyle**

If i create custom layout and change **style="?attr/detailsActionButtonStyle"** to **style="@style/Widget.Leanback.DetailsActionButtonStyle"**, then i can see correct styles

I tried rebuild project, clean project, tried remove and add leanback in dependencies - nothing.

How can I understand the problem in the studio or gradle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using the wrong theme, please, check that your theme is `Theme.Leanback`.